Not able to get the response header in Angular 16 with CORS
I am trying to access the response header from the post call but it seems there are "no headers" or I am going it wrong.
In the back end I am using ASP.NET Core. Here is my basic API:
[HttpPost("myTestApi")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestAPi([FromBody] TestApiRequestModel requestBody)
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    Response.Headers.Append("X-Test-Header", "Test Header");
    Response.Cookies.Append("TestCookie", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    return StatusCode(200, new { data = requestBody.Input });
}

The CORS configuration is:
var AngularApp = "AngularApp";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: AngularApp,
    policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

app.UseCors(AngularApp);

In the angular app I have the bellow code:
public TestAPICall()
{
return this.http.post("https://localhost:7227/api/myTestApi", {input: "xyz"}, {observe: 'response'})
.subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.headers.get('Set-Cookie'));
      });
}

The res returns the response data {"data": "xyz"} but I could not find a way to access the headers. I want to access the custom header TestCookie and the Set-Cookie coming with the response.
I have tried a few things such as TestAPICall():Observable<HttpResponse<any>> and post<Response> then try to access headers: res.headers.get("Set-Cookie") but it is undefined.
I guess it make no sense as post returns a Observable<object>.
EDIT:
using {observe: 'response'} I can read only the "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" but custom header and Set-Cookie are still missing.

From server especially for the endpoint where you want to read headers, you should have this under response headers.
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : 'set-cookie' upon this header present you should be able to access it

@sunilbaba sorry didn't get you. Can you please elaborate in an answer

@sunilbaba I have tried that as well.

I believe set cookie header would be done before your response.  It's a separate response that would go directly to the browser... the browser then writes the cookie and responds with something like "cookie written", and your response can then be sent.

@RahulChakrabarty - Are you able to access other response headers ? Facing issue for all headers / specific header ?

@sunilbaba Question is updated with current state :)

Are you sure the cookies sent from the server are not HTTP only? If that was the case, you won't be able to read them from JavaScript

Hi Rahul, please try to use WithExposedHeaders. Here is the sample: builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy(name: AngularApp,
policy =>
{
policy.WithOrigins(" http : //localhost:4200")
.AllowCredentials()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.WithExposedHeaders("Set-Cookie", "X-Test-Header");
});
});

The Cookie returned from the server might be HTTP only (which cannot be accessed through the JavaScript code)
The custom header should be included in the CORS access control allow headers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), something like this:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Test-Header


I have tried it prior to the question I posted. I thought that using Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *  should have worked but it did not.


trying to access the response header from the post call

To achieve your requirements of accessing response headers, you can try to modify your code like below.
API action method
[HttpPost("myTestApi")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestAPi([FromBody] TestApiRequestModel requestBody)
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    var new_guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Response.Headers.Append("X-Test-Header", "Test Header");

    //Browsers would block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the `Set-Cookie` header, 
    //set and store same data in header so that frontend JavaScript code can access the stored data
    Response.Headers.Append("X-Test-Cookie", new_guid);

    Response.Cookies.Append("TestCookie", new_guid);
    return StatusCode(200, new { data = requestBody.Input });
}

CORS configurations
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: AngularApp,
    policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowCredentials()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithExposedHeaders("X-Test-Header", "X-Test-Cookie");
    });
});

Angular frontend
public TestAPICall()
{
  return this.http.post("https://localhost:7227/api/myTestApi", {input: "xyz"},{observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.headers.get('X-Test-Header'));
          console.log(res.headers.get('X-Test-Cookie'));
        });
}

Test Result

